# Load Applicationcontext on startup (non Web application)

Tags: java, spring

I'm creating an application that use Spring Remoting.

I have my applicationContext.xml and i want to migrate it in a pure-code configuration.

Right not i have my main class with:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

I would like to "centralize" the loading and @Inject my bean when needed, without using:

```
UsersRepository userRepositories = context.getBean(UsersRepository.class);
```

For WebApplication i've seen WebApplicationInitializer.

but what if the application is not Web Based (no web.xml ecc)

Answer (score 0):

So, I cannot guarantee this is going to be entirely accurate, but here is how I do this.

In your service class (or whatever class is utilizing the UserRepository), you want to Make it an argument of the constructor and make it a global variable, add the @Inject tag above the constructor.  Here is an example.

```
public class UserService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository
    }
}
```

Like I said, this is how I do and we can access the repository freely from any of the methods in the class.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to annotate the UserService class with @Component (or define it as bean in XML, otherwise the injection will not happen.

Comment: I've done all this but when i @Inject i get a NullPointerException. I think this is caused by context loading from a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext... but i dont know how to solve this..

Comment: Have you added @Component to UserService class? And <context:component-scan base-package="UserService_package_name" /> is presented in your applicationContext.xml?